# What is the snapshot dependencies in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity-9.0

I've been reading the following two links to grab the idea of the snapshot 
dependencies.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Dependencies+Setup
 http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2012/04/teamcity-build-dependencies-2/

But I just want to make sure I understood correctly what I read from them.
So can someone explain it in a easy way please if possible?

Comment: Maybe if you tell us what your current understanding of it is and then we can say correct that if necessary, you might be able to get an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding the main reason using Snapshot Dependencies is for gain access to build parameters from builds that you depend on, by `%dep.<buildName>.xxxxx`.

For example, is you have a project MyProject with a Compile config, a Package config and a Upload config. I would set Package to have a Snapshot dependency on Compile and Upload to have a snapshot dependency on Package:

`MyProject
Compile <- Package <- Upload`

Then, if you run the Compile Job (passing in a version parameter) the Package and upload configs get added to the build queue, but will run in order once the build it is dependent on have built. 
As it is a Snapshot dependency Package can also access Compile's build parameter (version) by using `%dep.MyProject_Compile.version%`. Also because Upload has Package as a snapshot dependency it can also access it from the same location (`%dep.MyProject_Compile.version%`).

If you just ran an Upload config (say it failed and you fixed it and wanted to rerun), then only the Upload job will run - with will not trigger Compile and Package.

Note:
I am relatively new to TeamCity (used Jenkins for years before and there are some big differences when chaining builds/config).